# How to hide a option with *ngFor when user selects a option from the options?

Tags: typescript, angular6

I have two select with same options in my html and i need to hide a option if it is selected in any of the select. How to achieve it?

I have tried it with *ngIf but it doesn't seem to work.

```
app.component.html 
<section>
      <form>
         <label>Destination 1</label>
         <br>
         <select (change)="sendData(destination)" 
         [(ngModel)]="destination.d1" 
         [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >
         <option *ngFor="let i of sendDestination" value="{{i.name}}"> 
          {{i.name}} 
        </option>
         </select> 


      <label>Destination 2</label>
         <br>
         <select (change)="sendData(destination)" 
         [(ngModel)]="destination.d2" 
         [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >
         <option *ngFor="let i of sendDestination" value="{{i.name}}"> 
          {{i.name}} 
        </option>
         </select> 
      </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Probably best done with a combination of Observables, async pipe and filtering. https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-async-pipe-example https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5jARPyOlkM